# Ultra-light steerer cap idea

Tags: fork, headset, steerer

I want to run a brake hose through my steerer tube and need space for a clean exit.

My idea is to attach a kevlar spoke to the crown of the fork using the fender attachment point. Then I can run that inside the steerer to a length of threaded tube which the steerer cap is screwed into. I will fit a sleeve at the top of the fork to handle the pressure from the stem.

The Kevlar is easily strong enough for the preload and then my steerer is empty and I don't need to make a custom expander plug.

Aside from the hassle of it, do any of you experts see a problem with this?

Comment: Or you could use a bmx style cap and bolt designed for purpose like the one dia-compe make etc

Comment: https://www.ison-distribution.com/english/product.php?part=HSDCSNCFS

Comment: "I will fit a sleeve at the top of the fork to handle the pressure from the stem." — This is going to be the tricky part. I see the logic in what you propose, but it seems the industry prefers to internally route hoses through specialized headsets rather than the steerer.

Comment: Nice idea! At least for carbon steerer tubes I’ve heard that the expander plug is actually necessary to avoid deformation of the tube from the clamping forces of the stem. So you can’t just take it out. Not sure how true it is though.

Comment: The problem with through bolts is their size. A brake hose is 5mm. Plus I want a dyno wire to come up too.

Comment: The problem with specialized headsets is they are pretty hard to find in the right size. 44mm seems totally off the market and I would like to use my Chris King. There's not really space for a 5mm hose when you account for the head tube width and a bearing.

Comment: I will use a sleeve to manage the crushing force. A few people do that who use the tube for EDC.

Comment: *At least for carbon steerer tubes I’ve heard that the expander plug is actually necessary to avoid deformation of the tube from the clamping forces of the stem* It better not be.  No manufacturer requires a steerer tube to be cut short enough that the stem must clamp on where the expander plug is.  For example, such instructions are completely lacking in the Trek Emonda assembly manual: https://trek.scene7.com/is/content/TrekBicycleProducts/TK20%5F2021%5FEmonda%5FSL%5FSLR%5FUSEN.pdf

Comment: @Michael The odds of wanting a through-steerer brake hose and having a carbon steerer on the same bike seems very small to me.

Comment: So you're doing a Potts mod ?  http://i128.photobucket.com/albums/p191/mcseforsale/DYNO_RESTORATION/COMPLETE/DSC01698.jpg

Comment: Criggie - yes, pretty much. Just way neater at the top. Should look pretty integrated.

Comment: Might as ditch the steerer cap and the nut, just make sure to use friction paste and check the fork for play regularly. I run this setup on my MTB for a couple of years and it was fine.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks but I found a better solution. A plug with ample space for routing. I will fabricate a custom top cap to go with that.

https://www.intend-blackline.com/products/smarty/

[image: ""] 
 [image: ""]

Comment: Excellent find. Seems like a much better solution.

Comment: Really nice piece of engineering too. I am surprised this design isn't more popular. Clever German guy with great service. Unfortunately shipping cost more than the piece itself!

Comment: Ah, intend. The guy is a technical genius with pricing to match.

Answer (score 0):

The top cap serves two purposes:

1. To set bearing preload in the headset.  This is convenient but not at all essential; you can set preload using any reasonable method of putting downward pressure on the stem while you clamp it.
2. To prevent injury in a crash.

You need the top cap for (2) but not for (1) which means your kevlar spoke idea is unnecessary.  I suppose you're going to drill a couple holes (or a slot) in it for your brake hose and dynamo wire.  Then I suggest you simply glue the top cap to the stem, it only needs to hold the force of the hose and wire and if it pops off it isn't going to cause a crash, so you don't even need "permanent" adhesive, you can use glue which is just moderately strong so the top cap can be separated from the stem later if needed.

As usual, you need your steerer tube cut just a bit (~3mm) shorter than the top of the stem clamp, so the top cap can sit in place without hitting the steerer tube.  I assume you have no spacers above your stem.